# Populate Azure Table Storage Tables in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, populate

I am trying to find a good way how to populate Tables of Azure Table Storage just once with C#. Right now, I am creating the tables I need at startup using the *CloudTable.CreateIfNotExistAsync()*. I mean I could check if the initial entries I need, are already inside and if not create them but maybe there is a more clever way to do it. Maybe the C# SDK has some mechanisms I didn't recognize yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean I could check if the initial entries I need, are already inside
>   and if not create them but maybe there is a more clever way to do it.
>   Maybe the C# SDK has some mechanisms I didn't recognize yet.

For your scenario, I would recommend [`InsertOrReplace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.tableoperation.insertorreplace?view=azure-dotnet) operation on entities which will either create an entity if it doesn't exist or replace it if it exists.

```
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");// new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);

var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();

var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Customer");
table.CreateIfNotExists();

var entity = new DynamicTableEntity("partitionkey", "rowkey");
entity.Properties.Add("key", new EntityProperty("value"));

var operation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);

var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(operation);
```

Other option could be to try to create an entity and catch `StorageException` that will be thrown if the entity already exists.